# Imageview stucked at the top of android layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have put two linear layouts, under the first linear layout I have put the "textview" and In the second one I have put "imageview". But the problem is that image view is not moving, I want that dice icon in the centre. Whenever I try to drag that icon it gets stucked at the top left corner of the layout.

I can't figure out what's going wrong as I am new to android.

Have a look at the screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJmEY.png

activity_main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Logo"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/five" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.snakes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot drag elements in a LinearLayout. They are placed in the order they are declared in the layout file, depending on the orientation set (either horizontally or vertically).

There is also no reason to have two linear layouts like this in your case. You can place both of your elements inside of the first one, and use the gravity property to center the image view (ex. gravity = "center_vertical").

EDIT: 
I ended up trying it myself, and resolved it using a RelativeLayout inside a LinearLayout. Make sure the RelativeLayout matches the parents width and height, then center the ImageView inside of the RelativeLayout, like so:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/someImage"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have put both textview and image view under first layout and also used the gravity property, still it is stucked at the top

Comment: Updated my answer, try to see if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to the second linear layout - constraints statements. I can't recall the exact name of them but I think It's something like "layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf". this should make them constraint. then if you want you can determine the gap and adjust the view.